# Integrating Backbone with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

Trying to fetch Nodejs response from Backbone Model.

**Update**
Changed Model code as following and getting error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost:3000/getDifficulty`. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

```
var Bitcoin = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url:'http://localhost:3000/getDifficulty'
});

var info = new Bitcoin ();
info.fetch();
```

Node JS is very straight forward and works fine for the url `http://localhost:3000/getDifficulty`

**Server side Node JS**

```
var http = require('http'),
    express = require('express'),
    bitcoin = require('bitcoin');

var app = express();

var client = new bitcoin.Client({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8332,
    user: 'himanshuy',
    pass: 'xxx'
});

app.get('/getDifficulty', function(req, res) {
    client.getInfo(function(err, info) {
        if(err) {
            res.send('Bitcoin error: '+ err);
        } else {
            res.send('Difficulty: ' + info);
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**Client Side Backbone Model**

```
var Bitcoin = Backbone.Model.extend({
             urlRoot:'http://localhost:3000/getDifficulty' 
});

var info = new Bitcoin();
```

It works fine if give some value to the model like this

```
var info = new Bitcoin({version:"1.0.0.", balance:"20.03"});
```

Which means that model is not getting the result from url.

Please help.

> Note: I am fairly new to both backbone and Nodejs

Comment: You probably want to use `url` instead of `urlRoot` (`urlRoot` is for models that have ids, like `/getDifficulty/123`) and you also need to call `.fetch()` on your model to make it actually do the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
var Bitcoin = Backbone.Model.extend({
         url:'getDifficulty' 
});

var info = new Bitcoin();
info.fetch();
```

And take a look at the console to see the response from the server. From the looks of it, the above won't work, because you're not returning a json object `res.send('Difficulty: ' + info)`. Backbone expects JSON data to be provided (and only JSON) so it can load the values into the model instance.

If what you're returning from the server needs to be modified before being loaded into the modekl, you need to implement the `parse`function (see http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse):

```
var Bitcoin = Backbone.Model.extend({
         url:'getDifficulty',
         parse: function(response){
             // the return value should be what needs to loaded into the model
             // for example, if we need to only have the `data`attribute in the model:
             return response.data;
         }
});
```

Comment: How about `http:\\localhost:3000` part of the url? Is bitcoin smart enough to figure that out?

Comment: It has nothing to do with bitcoin: backbone urls are relative

Comment: Sorry, I meant `Backbone`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting errors like

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

You may need to configure your browser to disable CORS or web security settings. [This Chrome extension should get around that error.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)

In Firefox, [Force CORS extension is helpful.](http://www-jo.se/f.pfleger/forcecors)

Launching Chrome with a certain command line argument can also prevent these type of errors, but at the cost of vulns like XSS becoming easier to suffer: On Windows in the target field, this works - with the consequence of lower browser security as well:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security
```